# Plotting variable means for each level of the independent variable. R

Tags: r

Given the next code and dataframe:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

dat1 <- fread('J  S1  S2  S3  S4  Z
              1   4   5   3   2  0
              1   6   5   6   5  1
              2   3   5   8   9  0
              2  12  11  34  44  1
              3  11  23  23  22  0
              3  12  15  22  21  1')

temp <- melt(dat1, id.vars = c("J", "Z"))

ggplot(temp, aes(x = J, y = value, color = variable, shape = as.factor(Z))) +
  geom_point()
```

I'd like to plot in the same graph the mean of values (S1, S2, S3, S4) for each level of J. I mean, for S1, get 3 points in my graph: 5.5, 7.5, 11.5. For S2, another 3 points, and so on...

I'm trying this:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x = J, y = mean(value), color = variable, shape = as.factor(Z))) +
      geom_point()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KWaJ.png)

I get only one point for each full set of data. But I'd like to get in the same graph the mean of S1 for each level of J (1,2,3), the mean of S2 for each level of J, the mean of S3 for each level of J, and the mean of S4 for each level of J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add rows for mean in your data.

Please let me know if this make sense or you wish to have something different.

You can do:

```
library(data.table)

temp1 <- setDT(temp)[,.(value = mean(value)),by=.(J,variable)]
ggplot(temp1, aes(x = J, y = value, color=factor(variable))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

OR you can do :

```
ggplot(temp1, aes(x = variable, y = value, color=factor(J))) +
  geom_point()
```

**EDIT**, after OP's request:

To get Z variable into account, you need to summarize the data basis Z as well like below and then plot:

```
temp1 <- setDT(temp)[,.(value = mean(value)),by=.(J,variable,Z)]

ggplot(temp1, aes(x = variable, y = value, color=factor(J),shape=factor(Z))) +
  geom_point()
```

Now the plot contains three categorical variables, "variable","J" and "Z", you can play with them by switching them interchangeably to see what fits your need, don't forget to use factor() before them in case you want to use shape and color in the aesthetics. If you want to draw a graph for 0s and 1s separately then you have to use facet_wrap, like below:

```
ggplot(temp1, aes(x = variable, y = value, color=factor(J),shape=factor(Z))) +
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Z)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps. However, I've tried to explain better what I want to get in my plot. I do not want three levels of Z. I want the means of S1, S2, S3, S4 for each level of J.

Comment: thanks! This is much more similar to the thing I want. But I don't know why I have an error when I run temp1 <- temp[,.(value = mean(value)), by=.(Jugador,variable)]
Error in `[.data.frame`(temp, , .(value = mean(value)), by = .(Jugador,  : 
  unused argument (by = .(Jugador, variable))

Comment: @pyring have you converted the data.frame to data.table , like setDT(temp), I have edited that part you must be able to run it now.

Comment: that's great. My datafile is much bigger, so imaging that i want also to represent S1, S2, S3, S4 for each level of Z. Thus, if Z has 2 levels, 0 and 1, how could i represent factor Z with "shape" (not with colour), in this same graph.

Comment: @pyring , See the EDIT part, also request you to ask all questions at once, if you have more question, kindly ask in a separate question.

Comment: thanks so much. That answer is all I wanted to learn so far. Great answer.